# Fix missing commit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm new to Git. We're using Bonobo Git Server as the back-end and TortoiseGit for the client. When I do a pull I get the following in TortoiseGit -

```
POST git-upload-pack (328 bytes)
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: <!DO
fatal: write error: Invalid argument


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)
```

Bonobo's error log says -

```
   GitSharp.Core.Exceptions.MissingObjectException: Missing commit commit 903228ffc07ea920fd944c6fcdd5d8d5ef852ff1 0 ------
```

I've found the missing `903228ffc07ea920fd944c6fcdd5d8d5ef852ff1` file on one of the developer's machines under `.git\objects` folder. How do I put this on the server and get the repo working again? Please help.

I read on a different thread that I need to `repack` it and push it to the server? How do I do that? I'm a newbie at Git. I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First backup the corrupted repository in case you make things worse.

Then just copy the good file to `git/objects/90/3228...` on the server.

See [Recovering from repository corruption](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#recovering-from-repository-corruption) for more information.

If there are lots of missing objects you can indeed send them in a pack:

1. On the server, find the SHA-1 sums of the missing objects

   ```
   git fsck | grep missing | grep -o '[0-9a-f]\{40\}' > missing
   ```
2. On the developer's machine, pack the missing objects

   ```
   git pack-objects --stdout < missing > objects.pack
   ```
3. On the server, unpack the pack file

   ```
   git unpack-objects < objects.pack
   ```

Comment: The server does not have the git/object/90/* directory. All it has is info & pack folders under object folder.

Comment: You can create the `90` directory.