# git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) write error: Bad file descriptor

Tags: github, tortoisegit

Since a couple of days I have a problem to pull/push on Github on the origin branch.
I use git with TortoiseGit.

I got this error message on push:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

I got this error message on pull:

```
git.exe pull -v --progress       "origin"
Cannot chdir to , the toplevel of the working tree

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (6771 ms @ 20.09.2013 10:01:25)
```

And I think it has to do with my local working tree.
the view of the commit log shows in the top row after every new commit "`Working dir changes`"

in below in the description area there stands:

```
SHA-1: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Working dir changes 
files changed
```

What I have done:

- TortoiseGit clean up:
  clean Type

  - Remove all untracked files (`-fx`)
  - Remove untracked directories (`-d`)

What can I do to recover a coherent repo locally?

Answer (score 1):

IF it is your working tree/index which is somehow corrupted, you could:

- try the hard way, and [find the missing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745302/6309)
- try the easy way first, and clone again your GitHub repo in a different directory.

I would try the second approach first.