# git rebase: passing multiple strategy options

Tags: git

With `git rebase`, a merge strategy option can be passed using `-X <strategy-option>` or `--strategy-option=<strategy-option>`.  It's unclear from the man page, however, whether multiple options can be passed (or if subsequent options replace previous ones) and, if so, whether the correct syntax is `-X <opt1,opt2>` or `-X <opt1> -X <opt2>`.  Running `git rebase --verbose -m -X <opt1> -X <opt2>  <upstream>` does not produce errors, but even with verbose output enabled there is no indication whether both options were applied or only the last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `opt1,opt2,opt3` comma-separated syntax is used for [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Xltparam1param282308203gt)

```
D:\git\git\t>grep -E "\-X" *.sh|grep "\,"
t4047-diff-dirstat.sh:  test_must_fail git show -X=20,cumulative
t4047-diff-dirstat.sh:test_expect_success 'explicit defaults: -Xchanges,noncumulative,3' '
t4047-diff-dirstat.sh:  git diff -Xchanges,noncumulative,3 HEAD^..HEAD >actual_diff_dirstat &&
```

Not for strategy-options in merge/rebase.

For those, multiple `-Xopt1 -Xopt2` are needed.

But I can find only one instance where such a syntax is tested, and for a fail case: [`t3418-rebase-continue.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8dca754b1e874719a732bc9ab7b0e14b21b1bc10/t/t3418-rebase-continue.sh#L96)

```
test_must_fail git rebase -i -s funny -Xopt -Xfoo master topic
```

So in practice, I am not sure if this would ever be used.

The [initial commit (Nov 2009, Git v1.7.0-rc0)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee2c79552acceaa59a78518c6c084bd515606374) which introduced `-X` only tested with *one* strategy option at a time.

I see one example howhever, with git cherry-pick:

D:\git\git\t>grep -E "-X.*?-X" *.sh

t3418-rebase-continue.sh:               test_must_fail git rebase -i -s funny -Xopt -Xfoo master topic
t3510-cherry-pick-sequence.sh:  test_expect_code 128 git cherry-pick -s -m $mainline --strategy=recursive -X patience -X ours initial..anotherpick &&

See [`t3510-cherry-pick-sequence.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8dca754b1e874719a732bc9ab7b0e14b21b1bc10/t/t3510-cherry-pick-sequence.sh#L68), which [uses the same strategy/options as git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt---strategyltstrategygt).

```
test_expect_code 128 git cherry-pick -s -m $mainline --strategy=recursive -X patience -X ours initial..anotherpick
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fact that varying syntax is used for provision of multiple `-X` options to different git subcommands.

Comment: @user001 I have found *one* example of *multiple* strategy options used: see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update -- looks like it may be possible to use multiple without overriding.  Is it obvious to you what is causing that cherry-pick command to exit with status 128, which seems to indicate an unexpected error (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8059956/873757)?

Comment: @user001 Not sure. I have seen it in case of invalid file descriptor (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18939111/6309) Or a way to avoid -1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52902804/6309. Or as way to signal an invalid value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42797658/6309